# Fortran 2D grid w/ Periodic Boundary Conditions - efficient implementation

Tags: performance, multidimensional-array, fortran, fft, numerical-methods

I am using Fortran to solve some coupled PDEs using finite-differences and spectral methods. At a certain point those grids are fed into FFTW.
I assume the domain is periodic and I am struggling to find the most efficient way to deal with the problem of indexing. Options:

### 1 - Ghost Cells:

I define my grids as

```
real :: y(0:nx+1,0:ny+1)

(do finite differences)

call update_ghost(y)
```

Problem :
when I use FFTW I want the input to be the grid without the ghost cells, so I do:

```
call fftw(phi(1:nx,1:ny),phi_k)
```

and this leads to temporary array creation since the data is not contiguous.

### 2 - Indirect Adressing:

```
real :: y(nx,ny)
```

I then calculate vectors with the coordinates of the neighbours taking into account PBC then do

```
do j=1,ny
   do i=1,nx
      laplacian(i,j) = y(xnext(i),j) + y(xprev(i),j) + ...
   enddo
enddo
```

Problem: Indirect Adressing is expensive

### 3 - Calculate indices inside the loop

```
do j=1,ny
   do i=1,nx
      xnext = modulo(i+2,nx) + 1
      ynext = modulo(i,nx) + 1
      xprev = modulo(j+2,ny) + 1
      yprev = modulo(j,ny) + 1
      laplacian(i,j) = y(xnext,j) + y(xprev(i),j) + ...
   enddo
enddo
```

Problem: extra calculations

Does anyone have any other options? Right now I use option 1 but it kills me to think of all the temporary array creation that is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: You do not have to always create new temporary arrays. Create one yourself and just copy the data. Does it cost some time? It does. Is it too much? Measure!!!

Comment: Let me see if I understood:
```
real :: y(0:nx+1,0:ny+1),infft(nx,ny);

infft = y(1:nx,1:ny);

fftt(infft,out);
```
Is this it?

Comment: Yes.                         Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.                .    .

Comment: Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Another way related to 3 (which BTW I think you have mis-wrote) might be to loop over the centre cells where you know you do NOT need the modulo function, and then treat the edges separately. But you will have to time each solution to know for certain which is the fastest,

Comment: That is also a good idea. And yes it is miswritten :) I am gonna benchmark.